# Querying greater than values in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have got a table named workers and it has a field named age, how do I select all the columns from the workers table for workers over the age of 50?

Comment: A simple google search should help.

Comment: Any tutorial or book on SQL would have given you the answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM workers where AGE > 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM workers WHERE age > 50
```